# Woocommerce how do i center the add to cart button on a single page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

How do i center the `add to cart` button:

Here is the section:

[image]

You can find the page here:

https://silverblaar.tmmbuilds.com/product/full-spectrum-cbd-health-oil/

I have tried the following code but it's not working:

```css
.woocommerce div.product form.cart { 
  float:none !important; 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply center quantity selector and button by adding these CSS

```
form.cart {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: baseline;
}
```

[image: center]

regards

Answer (score 1):

Target the form  and use the `text-align` to center it!

```css
.woocommerce div.product form.cart{
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image]